# Countably infinite Cartesian product of finite sets is infinite

Tags: logic, set-theory

Say that $A \neq \emptyset$, but $\emptyset \in A$. With the term "infinite set" I mean uncountable or countably infinite. I want to prove that

$A \times A \times \cdot \cdot \cdot A \times \cdot \cdot \cdot$

is an infinite set either if $A$ is finite or infinite. If A is countably infinite, I now how to proceed and I now that is true that the infinite Cartesian product is infinite. If A is finite, I simply would  show that the cardinality of the above set is $|A| * |A| * \cdot \cdot \cdot$, so basically infinite. Am I right or am I missing something? Three questions (provided that my intuition is true):

1. if this result is true, does it hold even if $A$ has only two elements (as inferred by the assumptions)?
2. If $A$ is finite, the countably infinite Cartesian product is countably infinite or uncountable? I think it is countably infinite.
3. What about the case of $A$ uncountable? I think the product should be also uncountable.

Thanks.

Comment: The answer of halrankard seems to be the solution to my problem!

Comment: @Integrand:  Here the question is about product, not union

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your set:

$$
A\times A \times \ldots \times A \times \ldots
$$

can be written as $A^{\mathbb{N}}$ (the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$).

The cardinality of $A^{\mathbb{N}}$ is $|A|^{|\mathbb{N}|}$. This cardinality is infinite if and only if $|A|\geq 2$ (and in this case it is *uncountably* infinite).

So:

1. If $A=\emptyset$ then $A^{\mathbb{N}}=\emptyset$.
2. If $|A|=1$ then $|A^{\mathbb{N}}|=1$.
3. If $|A|\geq 2$ then $A^{\mathbb{N}}$ is uncountable.

The proof of (3) is a standard/famous exercise using Cantor's diagonal argument. Note that it is enough to prove (3) in the case that $|A|=2$. This is because if $|A|\geq 2$ then, letting $A_{0}$ be any $2$-element subset of $A$, observe that $A_0^{\mathbb{N}} \subseteq A^{\mathbb{N}}$.

For the case $|A|=2$ you may as well assume $A=\{0,1\}$. This puts $A^{\mathbb{N}}$ in 1-1 correspondence with the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$ (identify a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with its characteristic function). The proof that the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable (using Cantor's diagonal argument) is worth trying on your own, if you haven't already. It's also easy to find in this network.

Comment: Thank you very much, then if I've understood well your answer I was partly correct. Then in every case, $A$ finite, countably infinite or uncountable, whenever $A$ has at least two elements, its infinite product is uncountable, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks! I once proved Cantor's diagonal argument, I will go back and redo it. One more thing: $|A| = 2$ then $A^\mathbb{N}$, is true even if one of the two elements of $A$ is the empty set right?

Comment: Yes. The cardinality of $A^{\mathbb{N}}$ does not directly depend on the elements $A$ contains, just its cardinality. In other words, if $|A|=|B|$ then $|A^{\mathbb{N}}|=|B^{\mathbb{N}}|$. This is another worthwhile exercise. So this justifies the part of my explanation where I say "you may as well assume $A=\{0,1\}$".